# What Analysis to use, Likert scale variable vs continuous variable?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

I have 30 independent Likert scale variables and a continuous dependent variable. I am trying to find the strength and directionality of association between them. Pearson might not be the best approach for this kind of data. What type of analysis can I use?

Comment: I read that treating multi level categorical as continuous as erroneous. I tried Spearman correlation, and didnt get any useful insights.

Comment: Difficulty using Likert scores with Pearson $r$ is not lack of continuity, but the fact that Likert scores are not interval-numerical. // Cautions notwithstanding, many soc sci researchers seem willing to treat Likert data as numerical. // Likert scores are ordinal. Spearman $r_S$ uses ranks, and ordinal data can be ranked. // As in my exmp there may be little numerical difference btw $r$ and $r_S.$ // Still feel Spearman correlation is good choice. // You do not seem to feel my Answ is helpful. Anyhow no comments on it. So maybe I'm not the best person to try to make sense of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are fake data (simulated in R) with a nonlinear association between integer scores 1 through 6
and a continuous variable.

Both Pearson $r = 0.798$ and Spearman $r_s = 0.791$ correlations  are given.
Spearman correlation is Spearman correlation of the ranks of the two variables.

[image]

```
set.seed(2020)
x = sample(1:5, 100, rep=T)
y = rnorm(100, (x-1)^2, 3) + 10
plot(x,y,pch=20)
cor(x,y);  cor(x,y,method="spearman")
[1] 0.7982955
[1] 0.7911502
cor(rank(x), rank(y))
[1] 0.7911502
table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5 
19 21 23 19 18
```